# Getting the fields information of an Arcgis relationship table

Tags: javascript, arcgis, esri

I have a `FeatureLayer` that has several relationship tables "attached" to it. I can use the `RelationshipQuery` to request data that is related to an object on my layer. But the `FeatureSet` that is returned does not contain the fields information like the layer does. I need that information because I need to understand if the values are domain, for example. Bellow are two pictures to help visualize what I mean.

[image]

This pictures shows the fields found on the `FeatureLayer` object with all the information about the fields in the layer.

[image]

This pictures shows the object that comes from the `RelationshipQuery`, which has no fields information about this related table.

Can anyone point me in the right direction? When I access the URLs of the tables that information is there but there is no REST API for the tables itself, so a regular ajax request will just give me the html of the page.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From what I could gather, the easiest way to do it is to do a regular ajax get request and ask the server to send the json information so it's converted as an object.